# If a word in a foreach loop contains xxx, show previous word

Tags: c#, string

If a word matches with a string I compare with, I want to see the previous word I checked. Sounds very hard to understand, so I hope the code explains it a bit better:

```
String line = "qwerty/asdfg/xxx/zxcvb";
string[] words = line.Split('/');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (word.Contains("xxx"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word.Last);
        Console.Writeline(word.Next); //It doenst work this way, but I hope you understand the idea
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer for previous and next word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is have a variable that maintains the current state of your search. In your case, it's pretty simple as all you want to remember is the last word checked:

```
string line = "qwerty/asdfg/xxx/zxcvb";
string[] words = line.Split('/');
string previousWord = "";
foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (word.Contains("xxx"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(previousWord);
    }
    previousWord = word;
}
```

Comment: Genius. Can u edit the code also for the next word? :D

Comment: @wouter: I think you're being a little greedy. Don't you think?  you need to put some effort too.

Comment: @sstan youre right, it should be pretty easy to add the next word, im sorry for my greedyness, anyway thanks for the answer @Almo! :D

Answer (score 2):

Just store the last word you checked.

In addition, you should be using `String.IndexOf()` if you have any need for culture or case sensitivity awareness.

```
String line = "qwerty/asdfg/xxx/zxcvb";
string[] words = line.Split('/');
string previous = words.First();
string next = "";

foreach (string word in words)
{
    var currentIndex = (Array.IndexOf(words, word));
    if (currentIndex + 1  < words.Length)
    {
        next = words[currentIndex + 1];
    }

    if (word.IndexOf("xxx", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) > -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(previous);

        if (next == word) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The match was the last word and no next word is available.");
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(next);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        previous = word;
    }
}
```

In this particular case, "asdfg" is outputted as the previous and "zxcvb" is next.  However, if you are looking instead for "zxcvb" as the match, "The match was the last word and no next word is available." would be outputted.

Comment: I see, besides ur nice answer, I tihnk its easier to use  Almo's answer tho, because its a bit shorter and clearer :) If it dont work I will use ur answer tho, thank you for helping me out with this problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`

```
String line = "qwerty/asdfg/xxx/zxcvb";

string[] words = line.Split('/');
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    if (words[i].Contains("xxx"))
    {
        // Check to make sure you to go beyond the first element
        if (i - 1 > -1)
        {
            // Previous word
            Console.WriteLine(words[i - 1]);
        }

        // Check to make sure you to go beyond the last element    
        if (i + 1 < words.Length)
        {
            // Next word
            Console.WriteLine(words[i + 1]);
        }
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Results:

```
asdfg
zxcvb
```

### Without Loop

You could also use `Array.IndexOf()`

```
String line = "qwerty/asdfg/xxx/zxcvb";

string[] words = line.Split('/');
int index = Array.IndexOf(words, "xxx");

// Check to make sure you to go beyond the first element
if (index - 1 > -1)
{
    // Previous word
    Console.WriteLine(words[index - 1]);
}

// Check to make sure you to go beyond the last element    
if (index != -1 && index + 1 < words.Length)
{
    // Next word
    Console.WriteLine(words[index + 1]);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String line = "xxx/qwerty/asdfg/xxx/zxcvb";
 string[] words = line.Split('/');
  for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
   {
       if (words[i].Contains("xxx"))
        {
                Console.WriteLine(words[i]); //current word
                if (i == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("No Previous Word");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(words[i - 1]); //PreviousWord

                if (i == words.Length - 1)
                    Console.WriteLine("No Next Word");
                else                                           
                    Console.WriteLine(words[i + 1]); //NextWord
         }
    }
```

Comment: Bad index exception if the first word contains "xxx"

Comment: this will also throw an exception on the last word if it contains `xxx`

Comment: @bill: That won't fix it. indexing out of bounds doesn't return null, it throws an IndexOutOfRange exception

Comment: Answer is fixed, and is the only solution that provides the next word as the OP asked

Answer (score -1):

words[words.IndexOf(word) - 1] should do the trick.

Edit: Forget this. Almo's is nicer and not prone to Exceptions.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm curious: how does your thing work if there are duplicates of `word`? Does `IndexOf` operate by reference? I guess it would.

Comment: Duplicates are ignored. It takes the first occurrence of "word". But so does Almo's - without danger of an IndexOutOfRange exception. But you make curious: how would you like to handle possible duplicates?

Comment: Mine handles bloof/xxx/flarg/xxx fine. It prints "bloof" then "flarg". If IndexOf("xxx") always returns the first "xxx", it will print "bloof" twice. But i suspect it finds index of the reference, not of the value.

Comment: Mine *should* return value not reference. Can't test on iPhone now. Still the question remains: what to do with duplicates? Yours handles them fine - if they they need to be handled this way. Needs clarification.